Steiner Ellipse Half Axes Lengths
The are a number of Geometric constructions of the Steiner Ellipse of a triangle, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerCircumellipse.html
I am specifically interested in the construction using the Parry circle and Lemoine line. The Lemoine line intersects the Parry circle and the rays from the centroid of the triangle to these intersections give the axes of the Steiner ellipse. However the size of these axes is not discussed.
I was wondering wether the radius of the Parry circle plays a role in this. For example is there a result of the type: Suppose we have two triangles whose centroids coincide and their respective Lemoine lines are parallel. Then the direction of axes of the Steiner ellipses of the two triangles coincide (denote the directions $a,b$). Let $a_1,b_1$ be the distance from the centroid to the first Lemoine line along the directions $a,b$ and similiarly $a_2,b_2$ be the distances to the second Lemoine line. Denote $A_1,B_1$ the lengths of the half axes of the Steiner Ellipse corresponding the the first Lemoine line (and $A_2,B_2$ similarly for the second ellipse). Can we say that $a_1<a_2$ implies $A_1<A_2$ and a similar result for the $B's$.

Here's a counterexample:
The $A_i$ and $B_i$ are the "horizontal" and "vertical" radii of the (circum)ellipses shown, and the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the "horizontal" and "vertical" distances from the common centroid to the corresponding Lemoine axes.

We have
$$\begin{align}
a_1 &< a_2 &\quad b_1 &< b_2 \\[4pt]
A_1 &> A_2 &\quad B_1 &< B_2
\end{align}$$
So, the comparisons of the Lemoine distances need not both match (nor both reverse) the comparisons of the radii.
(Relating this your recent Steiner inellipse question: The circumellipse corresponding to the "closer" Lemoine axis need not be contained within the other.)

As with that other question, finding a plausible counterexample is fairly straightforward when starting with the ellipses in GeoGebra.
To construct an inscribed triangle with its centroid at the center, pick a point and dilate it in the center with scale factor $-1/2$; the line through the dilated point, parallel to the tangent at the chosen point, meets the ellipse at the other triangle vertices.
Constructing the Lemoine axis for the triangle depends upon how you characterize it. Conveniently, GeoGebra has built-in support for many Kimberling-indexed points from the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers, via the TriangleCenter() command, so knowing the Lemoine axis passes through $X(351)$ (the Parry center) and, say, $X(187)$ (according to MathWorld's "Lemoine Axis" entry) is enough to draw the line.
Now, one can derive a condition on the chosen triangle vertices to force the Lemoine axes to be parallel. (My own GeoGebra sketch incorporates such a condition.) However, while merely exploring the plausibility of the conjecture, it's enough to fiddle with the ellipse parameters and the locations of the chosen triangle vertices until the Lemoine axes appear at least close to being parallel. The axes vary continuously, so one might reasonably conclude that the "close"-ness could be made exact; so, if the conjecture fails badly at "close", it's likely not true.

As OP may have an interest in the lengths themselves ...
I'll define
$$\delta_a := b^2-c^2 \qquad \delta_b := c^2-a^2 \qquad \delta_c := a^2-b^2$$
$$\sigma := \frac12(\delta_a^2+\delta_b^2+\delta_c^2)=a^4+b^4+c^4-b^2c^2-c^2a^2-a^2b^2$$
MathWorld's "Steiner Circumellipse" entry gives these formulas for the radii (eg, $A_1$ and $B_1$ in the figure):
$$\frac13\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2\pm 2 \sqrt{\sigma}}$$
The distances (eg, $a_1$ and $b_1$) from the centroid to a point on the Lemoine axis (in the direction of a radius of the ellipse), are
$$\frac{\sqrt{
  2 a^2 b^2 c^2 \sigma^2
   \pm \sqrt{\sigma} \left(
     \delta_a^2\delta_b^2\delta_c^2-a^2 b^2 c^2 (\delta_b - \delta_c) (\delta_c - \delta_a) (\delta_a - \delta_b)\right)
     }
  }{3\,|\delta_a\delta_b\delta_c|}$$
And the radius of the Parry Circle (thus also the distance from the centroid to the midpoint of the "hypotense" segment along the Lemoine axis) is:
$$p = \frac{a b c\,\sigma}{3\;|\delta_a\delta_b\delta_c|}$$
